# Why this code is not working ? Python

Tags: python, regex

The code is working fine when the text in clipboard has no email address or phone number i.e., when expected result is "Nothing Found"
For other case, it is not working. It is showing error -
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'matches'

```
#! python3
# contactDetails.py - Finds email and phone number from a page

import pyperclip, re

phoneRegex = re.compile(r'(\+\d{2}-\d{10})')     # Phone Number Regex
# email Regex
emailRegex = re.compile(r'''(
[a-zA-Z0-9._]+   # username
@                # @ symbol
[a-zA-Z0-9._]+   # domain name
(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}])# dot-something
)''', re.VERBOSE)

text = str(pyperclip.paste())
matches = []
for groups in phoneRegex.findall(text):
    phoneNum=phoneRegex.findall(text)
    matches.append(phoneNum)
for groups in emailRegex.findall(text):
    matches.append(groups[0])

if len(matches) >0:
    pyperclip.copy('\n'.matches)
    print('Copied to Clipboard:')
    print('\n'.join(matches))
else:
    print('Nothing Found')
```

Comment: See `'\n'.matches` - you definitely meant to join the items in the list.

Comment: Change the title and [Create minimal, complete and verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) That kind of title is vulnerable to getting flagged and closed.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comment by Wiktor Stribiżew, the problem is in this line

```
    pyperclip.copy('\n'.matches)
```

In particular, it is here

```
'\n'.matches
```

The first item `'\n'` is a string object, and has no property called matches that can be called. What you want is to do a .join as you had done two lines later i.e.

```
    pyperclip.copy('\n'.join(matches))
```